# Nix: removing a profile

Tags: nix

What's the proper way of removing a Nix profile? Just deleting the folders starting w/ `<profilename>` in `/nix/var/nix/profiles`, while making sure `~/.nix-profile` doesn't point to them? `--delete-generations` doesn't allow to delete the current generation of the profile

Comment: There was a discussion recently https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350016/what-to-do-with-nix-and-nixos-tags-previous-a-legitimate-question-on-hold ...

Comment: While profile can be created with normal `nix-env -p` invocation, there are no commands to delete it. This is more of inconsistency in Nix CLI. So you are actually right - remove directory ensuring no-one points to it and then run GC.

Comment: Why would you want to delete the current generation? You can create a new profile by adding or removing any software with `nix-env`, then `nix-collect-garbage -d` should do the trick, no?

Comment: @Zimmi48 AFAIK, (un)installing SW will create a new generation, not a new profile. Nix has inbuilt ways to remove generations but not profiles